# non-adult or prepubescent individual

Tags: word-request

An individual who has not reached puberty is called prepubescent. Can we call them a "minor"? Or can we call them 'non-adult'? Note that, we are not referring to their legal right, but only physical strength for sexuality is meant in the context. Such as:

> i. A prepubescent can't make a child.
>
> ii. A minor can't make a child.
>
> iii. A non-adult can't make a child.

Problem with the last two is that a person who is under the age of 18 can still make a child though.

Comment: This is an exceedingly poor topic to attempt to address without native fluency.

Comment: The term *adolescent* is useful here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Minor" is a legal term. Plenty of minors get pregnant.

"non-adult" is a ambiguous. I'd assume it means the same as "minor".

"Prepubescent" is a medical term, by definition a prepubescent can't get pregnant yet, but it sounds quite technical.  It would probably be best to say "children who have not reached puberty", or "prepubescent children". It is often better to use the adjective rather than the noun when talking about types of people.

The phrase "Make a child" is wrong.  "Get pregnant" (if you are talking about girls)  "Get a girl pregnant" (for boys)  "Have a baby" (could be used for either)

Be careful about writing empty sentences.  "A prepubescent boy can't get a girl pregnant" is an empty sentence, because the meaning of "prepubescent" includes "can't get a girl pregnant".  I don't know exactly what you want to say, nor why you want to say it.  But I am fairly sure that you would do better to completely rephrase.

Comment: to learn I'd ask. Can we really use 'prepubescent' with "children"? Actually a child is indeed prepubescent already. Like, we don't say 'a manly man' , yes we can say 'a brave man'. Maybe I am wrong if I can say, 'prepubescent individual' or ''prepubescent person'' would sound better; isn't it?

Comment: You can say "prepubescent children" because not all children are prepubescent.  However depending on your context  "Young children" may well be better.  I still don't know exactly want you want to say, nor why you want to say it.